# matSuffix makes mat-icon not horizontally centered in mat-icon-button

Tags: html, css, angular-material2

I am making a simple auto complete input field with a close button at the end that would clear the field

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput type="text">
    <button matSuffix mat-icon-button>
        <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <mat-autocomplete>...</mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

However, I noticed that the button does not scale properly with the mat-icon, and the icon appears a little off to the right of the horizontal center of the button. Tried text-align and float, but none works. I then removed matSuffix, the button is not positioned on the same line anymore of couse, but it scales with the icon and centers it correctly

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/10313. The fix is to apply font-size, width, and height (and possibly line-height) to the button to counter what mat-suffix does to it.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following style to align my icons better:

```
mat-icon {
  margin-right: 0px !important;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

This got rid of the space on the right (horizontal align) and moved the icon down a bit to align better with my calendar control or other input icons. Just make sure this doesn't break any other styling where mat-icons are used, in which case you will have to specifically style only the mat-icons for the inputs where needed and not apply this across the board.